# I need gui Ubuntu server

Tags: 10.04, server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get a GUI environment with Ubuntu Server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53574/how-to-get-a-gui-environment-with-ubuntu-server)

I am a desktop user (windows and I am trying to get a gui interface on a new install of 10.04 server how can I do this

Comment: That is a very open question. Please be more specific as to what the server does and what do you expect the gui to do.

Comment: related question -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/2093/how-to-install-gui-desktop-on-a-server/7611#7611

Answer (score 0):

Well a graphical interface feels more comfortable, it is of limited value on a server as most of what you are going to be doing is starting / stopping services, editing configuration files, and or installing software, all of which can be done from the command line.

It is overwhelming , the [Ubuntu Server Gide](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/index.html) is a great place to start, gui or not.

ssh + screen allows secure, remote access (use keys, disable passwords).

If you still want a graphical interface, try to install as light an interface as possible, perhaps fluxbox or openbox, or perhaps Lubuntu. If you are not familiar with Ubuntu yet you can always go with gnome or KDE, but that is sort of overkill and installs unnecessary packages.

Do not get the wrong idea, a traditional desktop is helpful as you learn the basics of a server, but many people find it less helpful in the long run.

A very nice alternate is any of the various web interfaces, from [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) to [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) There are interfaces you can purchase as well, such as cpanel.

The advantage of web interfaces are three fold

1. They are graphical.
2. You can access them from anywhere.
3. Unlike a "desktop" such as gnome or kde they are targeted at the activities you will do with a server.

The disadvantage is that they are a potential vulnerability as others can log in to the control panels, use strong password and fail2ban.

So, pick your poison, but I do suggest the Server Guide.