# Getting "Server unexpectedly closed network connection"

Tags: server

I created VM by using Jclouds API and by giving the public address in putty login into the VM. I tried to install GUI in VM by giving the below command

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

It is installed but while rebooting the Ubuntu server I am losing internet connection getting message like below:

```
sudo reboot

Server unexpectedly closed network connection
```

Then the server won't respond.

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Fetched 1,384 kB in 5s (235 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-next/ubuntu/dists  /precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-next/ubuntu/dists  /precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-next/ubuntu/dists  /precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used   instead.
ubuntu@ip-172-31-20-201:~$ sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop  Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Comment: your title question has an answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2093/how-to-install-gui-desktop-on-a-server. As for the second question -- it's normal for your cmoputer, when restarted, to drop the ssh connection. Once it reboots you can reconnect.

Answer (score 0):

Try these GUIs on your server:

KDE Plasma Desktop: `sudo apt-get install kde-plasma-desktop`

XFCE4: `sudo apt-get install xfce4`

LXDE: `sudo apt-get install lxde`

GNOME 3: `sudo apt-get install gdm`

```
       sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-next 

       sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
```

and then `sudo apt-get update`

```
sudo apt-get dist-update

sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

These will install a vanilla GUI for you ie. the GUI, without any accompanying apps like Amarok and Muon in the case of KDE Plasma Desktop.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,I am trying to install.How can i start the desktop do i need to run reboot

Comment: I suppose not. When installation is done it may ask you whether to stick to Ubuntu Desktop environment or switch to the vanilla GUI. If it doesn't, reboot your PC and see. Which vanilla GUI are you trying?

Comment: I didn't get any GUI.While running sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop getting some error messages and output pasted above please find it

Comment: Did you use the update command as well? Going by your comment, it should have been `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop`. That && is a joint command, not my statement.

Comment: I executed as joint command still getting same error message

Comment: @user3535043 Here. I've edited and fixed my commands. See my post now and try these. Sorry :)

Comment: Still didn't get any GUI and the command apt-get dist-update not working i tried with dist-upgrade.If restart i loose the n/w connection