# Ubuntu Server 14.04 Native Windows Installation

Tags: 14.04, server

Is it possible to install Ubuntu 14.04 Server Edition as a native windows application like the desktop edition (using wubi)?

Please guide, as I'm going to use server edition for the first time.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install GUI desktop on a server?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2093/how-to-install-gui-desktop-on-a-server)

Comment: @P.-H.Lin.. The referred question doesn't help me to my question. Why do U think it as a duplicate to that at least?

Comment: Sounds like you want to install the server version with desktop environment to me.

Comment: Wubi is deprecated. Don't use it!

Comment: @P.-H.Lin.. No! My requirement is completely different from what you are thinking of.

Comment: @DavidFoerster.. What should I use alternatively?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install Ubuntu server in a dual-boot setup with Windows, but aren't sure how to do that, I recommend that you

1. first [install Ubuntu Desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop) and pay particular attention to [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](/q/1366),
2. then re-configure the system to resemble the server installation ([source](http://www.darrinhodges.com/converting-ubuntu-12-04-lts-desktop-to-server/)):

   ```sh
   apt-get update
   apt-get install tasksel
   tasksel remove ubuntu-desktop
   tasksel install server
   apt-get install linux-server linux-image-server
   apt-get purge lightdm
   apt-get autoremove
   ```

   In `/etc/default/grub` set

   ```
   GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
   GRUB_TERMINAL=console
   GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=
   ```

   and finally run `update-grub`.