# What does '~$' mean?

Tags: command-line

I just reset my username and password and am logging in for the first time since reset. After entering username and password, I get a prompt

`username@ubuntu:~$`

What do I type in for that?

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: How did you "reset your username and password"?

Comment: @bheller1 From your comments on the answers, it sounds like Ubuntu's graphical user interface does not load anymore, ever since you changed your username and password. If that is the case, I recommend you [edit] your question to clarify this, as well as what you mean by "reset." Did you actually change your username, or just the password? How did you do it? Does the prompt literally show `username@ubuntu`, or does it show you actual username for `username`? *Or is the situation simply that you're still in the recovery shell or live CD/DVD/USB environment from which you repaired Ubuntu?*

Comment: the prompt shows my actual username: [username]@ubuntu:~$

Comment: I downloaded/installed "Ubuntu Server-14" Might this be the wrong software for a common user? (I'm typing this on my Windows PC). Several weeks ago I downloaded Linux Ubuntu 14.04 i386.iso desktop to a dvd. I also have a dvd with Ubuntu 64-bit marked on it. Any suggestions on whether to wipe out the current Server-14 and install one of the other kits I mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

The prompt `~$` means you are currently in your home directory (indicated by `~`) and you are a normal user (not super user) indicated by `$`.

For a normal user:

```
username@ubuntu:~$ pwd
/home/username
username@ubuntu:~$ whoami
username
```

For root (check `#`):

```
root@ubuntu:~# pwd
/root
root@ubuntu:~# whoami
root
```

To getting started to using the terminal read [this documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal) properly.

Comment: I'm new to ubuntu. Should I type one or both of the following:
'~$ echo "$PWD"
/home/foobar
~$ echo "$USER"
foobar'
Don't understand the linebreaking

Comment: What do you want exactly? check my edits..I have it easier for you now (used some commands instead of variables)

Comment: For a start, run the commands i have posted..check if you get the desired outputs.....YOU ARE GOOD then....read [this documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal) thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

Is this prompt a terminal/shell screen? If so, it denotes you are at your home directory. The `~` is shorthand for /home/$USER/ dir and the `$` denotes the line of the console in which your user is typing.

If you are confused by the terminal prompt, and are expecting a GUI Desktop, you may not have one installed or loaded (such as "Unity" or "GNome").

Try searching the web for various desktop environments for Ubuntu. The great thing about Linux/Ubuntu is options! Here is a default means of installing a desktop:

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

Check out this answer as well: [How to install GUI desktop on a server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2093/how-to-install-gui-desktop-on-a-server). I would encourage you to check out some other options first, then decide which you think you will like best.

You can spot check internet connectivity with:

`ping www.google.com`

or:

`curl www.google.com`

(if you dont have `curl` installed by default, see below)

From the command line, you can install most programs with the following command:

`apt-get install <package-name>`

For help, try `man apt-get`

Comment: My primary concern is how to respond to the ' ~$' prompt.

Comment: Im thinking you type whatever youd like the operating system to do. Could you be more clear on what youre expecting to happen?

Comment: heemayl & todd:
sorry for the confusion. I just need to know how to respond to the '~$' prompt and get up and running.

Comment: @bheller1 you **are** up and running, this is your system. What did you expect? (please [edit] our question to answer our questions).

Comment: couldn't edit your question. By "up and running" I mean get onto the desktop where I can load programs, access web, etc. for general use.
heemayl

Comment: clarification: I'm writing from another computer. My ubuntu is still awaiting a response to '~$' - heemayl

Comment: @bheller1 you may need to install a desktop environment. you can, however, load programs and access the web. check my updated answer.

Comment: @bheller1 How did you *get to* (or otherwise *start* using) the command-line interface on which `username@ubuntu:~$` now displays? Is this a virtual console (accessed like Ctrl+Alt+F1)? Did you boot in recovery mode, or perhaps from a live CD/DVD/USB? Are there instructions online that you followed but now are confused about how to finish using? If so, can you summarize them and also provide a link. (You can edit your question to provide this information.) I recommend holding off on attempting to install software until you, and we, have a clear understanding of how your current problem arose.

Comment: That line means:

`username` is your identity

machine name is `ubuntu` and you are logged in

Current directory is `~` which now is a shortcut for `/home/username/`

The prompt `$` means you can type here.

Welcome to your shell command line, aka read, evaluate, print and loop (REPL). I recommend `man bash` next, which is the name of the program that listens to your typing.

Comment: I had to do a clean re-install from a dvd. I've completed installation, have set new username and password (mainly using http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) and now I need to know what to do with the current prompt, username@ubuntu:~$. Would like to get GUI.
(Can't manage to edit previous messages for you.)

Comment: I think my best bet would be to wipe everything and start over. Since I was "flying blind" with the first install (going from question to question), could someone make specific recommendations on what to download for a clean install with a GUI? Thanks.