# My computer won't boot from usb, is that possibly because it currently runs ubuntu server?

Tags: boot, server, system-installation, usb

I need to reanimate my old samsung netbook which currently has Ubuntu server installed and I need a GUI, so I tried to make it run Ubuntu desktop. Downloaded the iso, made a bootable USB and the computer completely ignores it.

When I turn on the computer I can see the brand and enter the BIOS, but when I change the boot order to USB it just shows a black screen with a flashing underscore and nothing more happens. Booting from HDD works, but I have no idea what to do with Ubuntu server.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I've made bootable USB sticks before and I checked if the file was damaged, so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Is it possible that the installation image wasn't written correctly to the flash drive? Have you tried rewriting the USB drive?

Comment: Wouldn’t you like to just add GUI to the Server installation instead? https://askubuntu.com/questions/2093/how-to-install-gui-desktop-on-a-server

Comment: An no, booting (or the inability to do do) an installation media has nothing to do with what is already installed, if anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your USB problem, but ...

You don't need to reinstall to get desktop, just run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

in a terminal. This will install Unity desktop.