# Still running light weight ubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, 17.10

If i install ubuntu desktop environment on xubuntu I still run light weight ubuntu or I change it to ubuntu?

p.s. I'am new to linux

Comment: Than you ran Ubuntu with two desktop environments between which you can choose. It also depends on what command you use to install it you might get only the pure desktop environment or also some additional applications installed. But it wouldn't be that lightweight anymore (as you should see on the count of installed packages and amount of additional used disk space)

Comment: i use this command to install sudo "apt-get install ubuntu-desktop"

thank you for answer

Comment: Consider rather using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/7611/423684)'s code to hold it as lightweight as possible

Comment: It is the window manager which is light or heavy - Xubuntu uses a set of programs chosen not to have a large footprint, and the DE is designed not to need a lot of CPU and memory.  By having both desktops, you get the freedom to choose as @derHugo indicates, but you also end up with a slightly mixed system.

Comment: Most people do not consider any of the *-desktop to be light weight in any way, certainly not ubuntu-desktop. Light weight typically means do a minimal install and install say gnome-shell or openbox or xfce with as few packages as possible. The *-desktop are meta packages the pull in the window manager + lots of other stuff == not light weight at all, but the trade off is the -desktop are well configured and easy to use.

Comment: @CharlesGreen s/desktop environment/window manager` . The DE is what adds the "bloat" - all the extra apps and services that run at login, IMHO at least. See https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-desktop for all the "bloat" that comes with DE / ubuntu-desktop vs say gnome-shell https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gnome-shell