# Black screen with logon prompt on Raspberry Pi 3b+

Tags: login, 20.04, raspberrypi, tty

I'm new To Ubuntu. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Raspberry Pi 3b+ with Raspberry Pi imager and it boots to this black login screen.

```
Ubuntu 20.04 Ubuntu tty1
ubuntu login:
```

Comment: The "*login:*" is the login prompt for Ubuntu Server (a GUI uses extra resources, so servers don't waste the resources on running a GUI by default). Did you install a Ubuntu Server system?

Comment: @guiverc if it was installed via the standard Ubuntu image that's practically implied (i.e. being a "Ubuntu Server") ... unless, of course, extra steps were taken to install a desktop environment. Compare with the info from [this article](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/05/ubuntu-20-04-lts-is-certified-for-the-raspberry-pi). Quote: _Now, I should probably point out that when we talk about Ubuntu for the Raspberry Pi we don’t mean the desktop edition._

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install GUI desktop on a server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2093/how-to-install-gui-desktop-on-a-server) and [Switching between console and GUI](https://askubuntu.com/q/917320/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support for the Raspberry Pi implies that you are installing Ubuntu Server by default. Use [`tasksel`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel) or [`apt` (and friends)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto) to install a desktop environment to your liking.

If you look at [the official website](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi) you'll notice:

[image: Ubuntu Server explicitly mentioned on the official Ubuntu RPi website]

... so you get Ubuntu Server by default.

Oh, and in case you were wondering how to get into the system, simply follow the advice [from the documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi#First_boot_.28Username.2FPassword.29):

> The login username is "ubuntu", password is "ubuntu". You will be
>   asked to change the password on first login.

From there you should be able to either access `tasksel` via `sudo tasksel` or install it via `sudo apt update && sudo apt install tasksel`. I'm not sure whether `tasksel` is included by default, as I don't have the image handy at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You have have installed Ubuntu for Raspberry Pi 3B+. So, you will get Ubuntu Server by default.

So, to install desktop environment first you have update your system. To do this, issue these command:

```bsh
apt update
apt upgrade
```

Now you have to install your desired desktop environment.

To install the desktop environment which comes preinstalled with Ubuntu Desktop:

```bsh
apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

To install lightweight Lubuntu Desktop:

```bsh
apt install lubuntu-desktop
```

To install lightweight Xubuntu desktop:

```bsh
apt install xubuntu-desktop
```

To install lightweight Kubuntu Desktop:

```bsh
apt install kubuntu-desktop
```

Note that all commands must be run as user root or with sudo.

Hope you have got your desired desktop environment.