# Ubuntu 20.04 VPS, install GUI

Tags: 20.04, gui, vps

I have recently rented out a VPS, and installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 (x86_64-Minimal) on it. I installed SSH on it, and I'm accessing it from a Windows 10 machine using command line.
However, I want to install a GUI on it. I have looked around, used tasksel, installed gnome GUI, but I can still only access it as a console version. I have tried rebooting, I have tried pressing F1(?) to switch between GUIs (I read that somewhere), but nothing seems to work.

Can anybody help me set up a GUI on this VPS?

Comment: How did you try to access the desktop? I guess your problem may be that you need an X client (for X-server) on your Windows machine and that X11 forwarding has to be enabled in your terminal emulator. Then, you can open GUI applications and they will appear on your local machine.

Comment: I tried several things, I tried using RemoteNG and tightVNC, none of them worked. Can you please tell me more about this X client?

Comment: I used Xming back in the day, maybe you can check this out: https://superuser.com/questions/99303/what-are-my-x-client-options-for-ms-windows. But maybe this is not exactly what you want to achieve. This will allow you only to execute graphical applications that appear on your local desktop, but does not provide you a remote desktop. Maybe you have to install or start a remote desktop server on your VPS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install GUI desktop on a server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2093/how-to-install-gui-desktop-on-a-server)

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following command:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop --no-install-recommends
```