# Does Ubuntu Server 22.10 have a Graphical user interface setup?

Tags: server, 22.04, debian, 22.10

does the latest version of ubuntu servers, 22.04.01 LTS or 22.10 have a GUI ?!

if No!

**COULD I SWITCH FROM A CORE SETUP TO GUI (Graphical User Interface ) ?!**

Comment: Ubuntu Core is a different product from Ubuntu server. Ubuntu server does not come with any GUI. You may install one later.

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install GUI desktop on a server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2093/how-to-install-gui-desktop-on-a-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Install the ubuntu-desktop package.

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^
```

And reboot.

Comment: thank you. It did actually work