# PlayOnLinux on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: wine, playonlinux

I can't find the system requirements for PlayOnLinux, but all I got from their website is how to install on Ubuntu 20.04 - is it even possible to install it on Ubuntu 20.04 Server?

I tried to install PlayOnLinux_4.3.4 .deb (link below) on Ubuntu Server 20.04 and I got the message below - which make me think PlayOnLinux needs the GUI of Ubuntu Desktop:

"xrdb: Can't open display '' Unable to access the X Display, is $DISPLAY set properly?

https://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html ** PlayOnLinux installer for Ubuntu

I downloaded: > PlayOnLinux_4.3.4.deb Then installed as below:

`sudo dpkg -i playonlinux_4.3.4.deb`

Questions:

1. Is PlayOnLinux compatible with Ubuntu Server? If so, how do I fix the error above
2. Running my VPS with Ubuntu Desktop doesn't look good, do I have any alternatives?
3. I just need to run a MSDOS app, how do I get the command prompt in PlayOnLnx?

Many thanks

Comment: How about you tell us specifically what you actually want to achieve instead of how to fix something you tried that didn't work? What DOS app, and why?

Comment: You are correct, you need a GUI. However if a DOS app is all you need, can't you try DOSBox instead?

Comment: I've a console app that uses .NET libraries and if I run it with >Wine cmd.exe it doesn't work. So Matias thanks for confirming that POLnx needs a GUI. No, DOSBox doesn't work either, so I've installed Win 8 on a VM and it works. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install GUI desktop on a server?](https://askubuntu.com/q/2093/)